# How to reverse gsap timeline on mouseleave event?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to make a card hover animation with GSAP.

I created a function `cardAnim` that returns a card timeline `cardAnimTl`.
On mouseenter the timeline is played `cardAnimTl.play()`.
I want to reverse the timeline on mouseleave.
I tried `cardAnimTl.reverse()` but it doesn't work.

Here's the [link to the code on codepen](https://codepen.io/surajr1711/pen/JjXPQVK?editors=0010).

It plays but it doesn't reverse. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function in both the enter and leave event. That means that you're creating and returning the animation each time one of those events happens.

What you want to do instead is create the timeline *once* then use control methods on that timeline.

```
cards.forEach((card) => {
  const cardCover = card.querySelector(".card__cover");
  const anim = cardAnim(cardCover);
  
  card.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => anim.play());
  card.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => anim.reverse());
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/ZEWEYKb?editors=0010). I write more extensively about this subject in my [article on animating efficiently](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/).

FYI: You're more likely to get a faster answer over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Comment: Oh haha. So simple. Thanks for your help. GSAP is really awesome. Great article too.  I'll hit the greensock forums directly next time.